# Segmentation fault when accessing array element in Assembly

Tags: arrays, pointers, assembly, segmentation-fault

I call from C so:

```
calculate(&data[index + v], &data[i + v], &data[j + v], norm_1, norm_2, ps, remaining);
```

a function implemented in Assembly, this is the assembly function:

```
global calculate

current_point_a     equ     8
i_point_a           equ     12
j_point_a           equ     16
norm_1_a            equ     20
norm_2_a            equ     24
ps_a                equ     28
counter             equ     32

calculate:


        push        ebp             
        mov         ebp, esp       
        push        ebx             
        push        esi
        push        edi
;------------------------------------------------------------

        mov         eax,  [ebp+current_point_a]         
        movaps      xmm0, [eax]         ; HERE SEGMENTATION FAULT               
        movaps      xmm1, xmm0
```

when I try to access to an array element through its address passed from C function, I have a segmentation fault.

What is the problem?
I need to take from memory 4 contiguous elements of array.
How can I fix it?

I'm using GCC on Linux with 32 bit architecture.

Comment: Not enough to go one. are you compiling for x86 (32-bit) or x86-64(64-bit). What OS are you targeting the code to run on (Windows/Linux/OSX/ etc)? It would help if you gave a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @lurker: the first arg has the lowest address (smallest distance above the return address), so `[ebp+8]` is the first arg in a 32bit calling convention that passes all args on the stack.  (@ Guiseppe: This is not guaranteed, see the ABI / calling convention info in the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info).  Thanks for showing exactly which instruction faults, that's essential for asm debugging, but you didn't say which platform you're using, so we don't know how the C compiler will pass args.

Comment: @PeterCordes ah OK, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: We know you're not building 32bit asm source in 64bit mode, since in that case the load from `[ebp+current_point_a]` itself would fault.  (`rsp` is usually outside the low 32 bits of address space in 64bit processes.)

Comment: @PeterCordes How can i fix it?

Comment: By looking up the calling convention for the platform you're using, and finding out where your caller will put the first arg.  Or just look at the asm output from the compiler for a function like `void * foo (void *p) {return p;}` to see where it gets the value to put in `eax`.

Comment: @PeterCordes i can access to the element into [ebp+something..] but i can't access inside the memory at position contained in ebp+something.

Comment: Probably the data at `[ebp+something]` that you're loading is not your function arg.  This is what everyone has been telling you.  Look at it in a debugger, and see if it has the same value as the pointer you were trying to pass from C.

Comment: If the _C_ and assembly files  aren't overly long can you just provide it to create a minimal complete verifiable example. You'd likely get a better response. As it is, it is a guessing game.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it happens because you assume that arguments are passed through stack, which is not always correct. There are multiple [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) used by different compilers on different platforms. Say, [System V convention](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf) (used on Linux) passes some arguments through registers.

It's hard to say what exactly you should use in your case because it depends on OS, compilers and compilation flags. If you use GCC, you may see your C's program generated assembly code by passing the `-S` flag to the compiler and see yourself how exactly arguments are passed.